# How to (better) select with AS in Doctrine's query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am currently using this query and it works:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('u')
    ->addSelect('SUM(l.corrects) AS score')
    ->from(User::class, 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u.learned', 'l')
    ->groupBy('u.id')
    ->orderBy('score', 'desc')
    ;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But in twig I have to use `{{ user['score'] }}` & `{{ user[0].username }}`... What can I do so that I can use `{{ user.score }}` & `{{ user.username }}` in twig?

Comment: You can't, at least not without some work. The problem is that the groupBy instruction will return a simple array and is not magically linked to associated entities. If you dump your query result it may be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do that in your User entity ?

```
// User.php

public function getScore()
{
    $score = 0;
    foreach($this->learned as $learned) {
        $score += $learned->getCorrects();
    }

    return $score;
}
```

You'll be alble to use `{{ user.score }}`

Comment: Because it will require n + 1 queries instead of just one, right?